# listen on port and decrypt https to stdout

Tags: linux, https, listener

I write application that will send data to server over https. For development I would like to mock the server so that something listens there and simply shows me what it received, in decrypted form. Like `nc -lv 8000` only with decryption. How to do this in linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `openssl` as both a minimal SSL/TLS [**client**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/s_client) as well as a simple [**server**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/s_server)

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

and similarly to run a listener  on port 8000 (with a key and certificate) :

```
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 8000
```

or or even a simple (web) server:

```
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 8000 -WWW
```

Comment: close but no cigar - I have POST requests with unpredictable paths so I always get 403 forbidden (surprisingly not 404). Returning error is ok, but I don't get to see what was sent on stdout, only `140032553370048:error:1408F09C:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:http request:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:242: ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

Develop your application in a web framework that makes the request object available. Then log these or do whatever you like with them.

To access the characters on the wire, do packet capture and decode TLS from extracted secrets. [Wireshark is capable of TLS dissection.](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#SSL_dissection_in_Wireshark)

An advantage to this approach is that it also works against production traffic, rather than using toy mock or echo servers.